# Issue related to state maintenance

Tags: iphone

I have 10 views with `UINavigationController` in hierarchy. Now when I want to go back from 10 to 9, and so on with back button, which method  should I use?

1. `popviewController`
2. `popToViewController`

I have set a fixed value for all views. At application launch, I get that value. For that value I initialize `rootviewController` with use of `UINavigationController`. And my `rootviewController` is nothing but the first view and after that on next line, I'm pushing a particular view.

Comment: Please stop posting the same question over and over. This is the third time you've asked this question! Original (not mentioning the second one that was closed as duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447857/a-question-is-related-to-state-maintainance

Answer (score 0):

If you're pushing the views onto a `UINavigationController`, you don't need to explicitly set any method for the back button that the `UINavigationController` object manages, since it will pop the correct view when tapped. It's all automatic.